# Two different german words ("Raum", "Zimmer") both translates to "room"

Tags: translation, german

I'm searching for an English translation of "Raum" and "Zimmer". It is related with [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/14930/what-are-the-differences-between-raum-and-zimmer). Is a translation to two different words possible? Or is it only "room"?

To put this more into context:

"Raum" ... a place, where students come together to learn at the university for example. This could be lecture room, but not every room is a lecture room.

"Zimmer" ... The patient lies in room XY on ward YZ.

I think the solution would be to be more specific with room like KarlG said: living room, lecture room, waiting room, ...

Comment: 'Raum' often translates to 'space', as in 'Lebensraum' = 'living space'. 'Zimmer' is more like a place in a house that has a door and four walls. Words in human languages aren't like programming languages where one word means exactly one thing. Between languages, one word can be used where in the other language multiple words are used for different nuances of the original word, and it goes both ways.

Comment: _Raum_ as in _Weltraum_ can also mean "(outer) space". A _space ship_ is a _Raumschiff_. "Space and Time" would be "Raum und Zeit".

Comment: Perhaps "area" for *"Raum"* as in play area and dining area, which are not necessarily actual rooms.

Comment: Did you _have_ to choose Lebensraum?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about German, not English. The linked question resides on the German.SE site, so why not this one, especially since the question is *answered* there as well?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey tut mir leid. Yes, an unfortunate choice on my part.

Comment: Well, translation into English is on-topic, but questions need [**FAR** more data](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info) than is present here. The current answer would be suitable on German.SE and it provides a lot of the information which should actually be in the question!

Comment: "Room" can also be translated back into German as "Platz". Which can the be translated back into English as "place". Which can then be translated into German as "Ort". Or "Stelle", or "Stätte". Or "Fleck", which can then be translated into English as "spot", then into German as "Pickel", then into English as either "pimple" or "pickax". You see where this is going? As others have said, relations between words in different languages simply aren't bijective. That's why people love using Google to translate song lyrics into Chinese and back into English again. It just doesn't work. It can't.

Answer (score 2):

The word *Zimmer* is reserved for living spaces, or those quite similar: a doctor’s office may have, say, a *Wartezimmer* ‘waiting room’. A utility room in a home, in which no one lives per se, can be called a *Hauswirtschaftsraum*. *Lagerraum* ‘storage room’ can mean a room for storage or how much room/space is in a car trunk/boot. A single office is a *Büro* (bureau), but when speaking about working spaces in general, you’d likely say *Büroräume* (lit. ‘bureau rooms’), because as much as one might feel like it, one does not live at work. A hospital or hotel room is also a *Zimmer*, because one “lives” there if only temporarily.

Outside of domestic and commercial settings, *Raum* means ‘space’ not necessarily enclosed. A *Raumstation* is a space station.

If there isn’t enough room/space, say, in a suitcase for a bulky sweater, a living room for a giant sofa, etc. the word is *Platz*, cognate to Eng. ‘place’ and borrowed from the …er… same place.

Comment: *Zimmer* is cognate with "timber", and may also be akin more distantly to Latin *domus*, meaning "house".  *Raum* is cognate with "room", and, more distantly, with Latin *rus*, "open land, countryside".  Thus you might say *Zimmer* is an enclosed space often made of wood, whereas *Raum* signifies an open space.

Comment: @tautophile: Germans don't build many wooden houses these days, though the number is growing. And some _Räume_ really are rooms in English. The etymology is interesting, but not particularly relevant to distinguishing modern usage.

Comment: True enough, KarlG.